# How add dynamic the control(textbox and dropdownlist) in mvc and remove the seleted item from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In my  requirement I had two controls textbox and dropdown list ,need to create the controls dynamically and delete control dynamic based on buttons click using MVC

[image]

item are  is dropdownlist  once user selected the item than that selected item should not be shown to user in dropdownlist

```
  example :items:  1 bottle
                   2 bottles
                    3 bottles
```

if user select the "1 bottle" item that should not appear in dropdown list.

```
enter code here  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var initialData = new[] {
            new Gift { Name = "Tall Hat", Price = 39.95 },
            new Gift { Name = "Long Cloak", Price = 120.00 },
        };
        return View(initialData);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Gift> gifts)
    {
        return View("Completed", gifts);
    }

    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return PartialView("GiftEditorRow", new Gift());
    }
```

When I am click on button two controls are adding in different view(page), I want add I the below of the same page

Comment: I followed below link http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: here I don't know how to place ddl and bind data to ddl